# In Pokemon Ruby/Sapphire, is it possible to change the time?

Tags: pokemon-series, cheats

In Pokemon Ruby/Sapphire, is it possible to change the time? If I recall correctly, you can bring up some sort of UI for that but it required a code of sorts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've set the clock at the beginning of a new game, it cannot be changed (without some sort of save-game editor or Gameshark-esque device).  I really wish they'd put this in with the Berry Glitch patch.

Comment: Berry glitch patch?

Comment: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Berry_glitch